# Adding appointment to Outlook (2013) opens up the meeting editor

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2013

I am trying to add appointments to Outlook programmatically.

I ran this code which runs successful but after I save the appointment the meeting editor opens up in outlook.

```
AppointmentItem appItem = null;
                try
                {
                    appItem = outlookItems.Add(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) as AppointmentItem;
                    if(appItem == null)
                        continue;
                    appItem.Subject = "Subject";
                    appItem.MeetingStatus = OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
                    appItem.Location = "Location";

                    appItem.Save();
                    appItem.Display(true);

                }
                finally 
                {
                    if (appItem != null)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appItem);
                    }
                }
```

I tried calling Display(true), Display(false) it still doesn't work.
Please can anyone tell me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Why do you need to call Display at all?

Comment: I removed the call to Display... the entry is nt gettin saved.. seems like a problem with recipients...havent figured out a solution yet

Comment: Your code is not adding any recipients.

Answer (score 1):

But you create a new meeting item in the code setting the following property:

```
appItem.MeetingStatus = OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
```

If you don't want to see a new item window (inspector), there is no need to run the following line of code:

```
appItem.Display(true);
```

The [Display](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862445(v=office.15).aspx) method displays a new Inspector object for the item.

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article in MSDN helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if the appointment is of type `OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting`, recipients are supposed to be present.

I changed the type to

```
appItem.MeetingStatus = OlMeetingStatus.olNonMeeting
```

and removed the call to display. I was able to save the appointment in the calendar